# What is there in numbers?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

With three I am a type of age

one added, I become edible

one more, I can be a type of tag (not a **PSE** tag)

one more and stirred, I belong to a regal family

one more, we are more than one of above

one more, I belong to a regal family

two more, we are more than one of above

Who am I ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With three I am a type of age

> **ICE** age

one added, I become edible

> **R**ICE is edible

one more, I can be a type of tag (not a PSE tag)

> **P**RICE tag

one more and stirred, I belong to a regal family

> A royal family may have a PRI**N**CE

one more, we are more than one of above

> PRINCE**S**, the multiple of prince

one more, I belong to a regal family

> A royal family may have a PRINCES**S**

two more, we are more than one of above

> PRINCESS**ES**, the multiple of princess

Comment: Correct, that is pretty fast !